# how to get all elements of repeater under repeater

Tags: testing, automation, protractor

```
<item id="item-1" class="item ng-scope" ng-repeat="incident in $ctrl.allIncidents track by incident.dg_guid"><div role="tablist" class="panel-group" ng-transclude="">
    <div class="panel ng-scope ng-isolate-scope panel-default panel-open" ng-class="panelClass || 'panel-default'" is-open="$ctrl.isExpanded" style="">

  <div id="accordiongroup-1970-6335-panel" aria-labelledby="accordiongroup-1970-6335-tab" aria-hidden="false" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse in collapse" uib-collapse="
    <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.showTextArea -->
    <div>

            <!-- ngRepeat: event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy track by $index --><div class="incident-details__description-text flex-space-between ng-scope" ng-repeat="event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy track by $index">
                <div>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: time in event.date track by $index --><div class="timeline__time__container ng-scope timeline__container-first" ng-repeat="time in event.date track by $index" ng-class="{'timeline__container-first': $first}">
                        <span class="timeline__time ng-binding">8:39 PM</span><br>
                    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: time in event.date track by $index --><div class="timeline__time__container ng-scope" ng-repeat="time in event.date track by $index" ng-class="{'timeline__container-first': $first}">
                        <span class="timeline__time ng-binding">07/26/16</span><br>
                    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: time in event.date track by $index -->
                </div>                
                </div>
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy track by $index --><div class="incident-details__description-text flex-space-between ng-scope" ng-repeat="event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy track by $index">
                <div>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: time in event.date track by $index --><div class="timeline__time__container ng-scope timeline__container-first" ng-repeat="time in event.date track by $index" ng-class="{'timeline__container-first': $first}">
                        <span class="timeline__time ng-binding">7:08 PM</span><br>
                    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: time in event.date track by $index --><div class="timeline__time__container ng-scope" ng-repeat="time in event.date track by $index" ng-class="{'timeline__container-first': $first}">
                        <span class="timeline__time ng-binding">07/25/16</span><br>
                    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: time in event.date track by $index -->
                </div>
```

I am trying to get the timings of timeline__time

```
this.IncList = element.all(by.repeater('incident in $ctrl.allIncidents track by incident.dg_guid'));
this.FirtstIncTimeLine = this.IncList.get(0).element.all(by.repeater('event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy track by $index'));
this.FirtstIncTopTimeLine = this.FirtstIncTimeLine.first();
this.FirtstIncTopTimeLineTime = this.FirtstIncTopTimeLine.element.all(by.css('span.timeline__time'));
```

I am getting following error:

> Error: TypeError: this.IncList.get(...).element.all is not a function

How can I get all elements of repeater under a Repeater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem in Protractor, *you are doing the chaining incorrectly*, replace:

```
this.IncList.get(0).element.all(by.repeater('event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy track by $index'));
```

with:

```
this.IncList.get(0).all(by.repeater('event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy track by $index'));
```

FYI, if interested, I'm [currently working on making these kind of problems caught by static code analysis and `ESLint`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/36).

---

As a side note, don't use the "track by" inside the repeater locator:

```
this.IncList.get(0).all(by.repeater('event in $ctrl.timeline.filterBy'));
```

I've already implemented [the `ESLint` rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/use-simple-repeaters.md) to warn about that.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe this helped.